# How to get relative path from a file

Tags: java, relative-path

I'm  trying to get the relative path for a file but without success.The absolute path is:"/Users/dev/Documents/projects/testService/src/main/resources/response.xml". After i deploy my code I'm getting java.io.FileNotFoundException:(No such file or directory).

Can you please help me?
Thank you

0

The code looks like this:

```
 try {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/response.xml"));


        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            xsr.next();
            if (xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT || xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT ||xsr.isCharacters() == true || xsr.hasText() == true || xsr.getEventType() == XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT)
                continue;
            QName name = xsr.getName();
            int index = name.toString().indexOf('}');
            String aa = name.toString().substring(index+1);

         if (xsr.isStartElement() && aa.contains("Bonitae"))
               break;
        }

        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        response = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Customer.class);    
    }
```

On my local pc it's working fine. I deployed the project using a jar.

Comment: Could you paste the code you used as well, that would be helpful.

Comment: please show us your code or what you've done so far

Comment: In the snippet you posted you are already using a relative path?

Comment: /src/main/resources/response.xml - is it the same you get by clicking on file properties and path label

Comment: Where do you run your code from, the directory above `src`?

Comment: @OnkarMusale, if i click on copy path file i''m getting this: /Users/dev/Documents/projects/testService/src/main/resources/response.xml

Comment: /Users/dev/Documents/projects/testService/src/main/resources/response.xml - then add this path in your code

Comment: Doesn't working: -------------------------------------
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/dev/Documents/projects/testServie/src/main/resources/response.xml (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
On my locat desktop it works. After I deployed the project doesn't worked anymore

Comment: An entry inside a .jar file is not a file.  You cannot read it using FileReader, ever.  Only [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) will read it properly.